# How to use a BT speaker to create a 4.0 sorround

Tags: windows, windows-10

I recently bougth a bluetooth speaker and I can pair it with my laptop to substitute built in speaker.

Since also built in speaker are working well I whould like to use both pair of speakers, but I'm not able to do that using windows panels...

I'm using windows 10, and Dell Audio since I have a Dell Inspiron 15

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually mean 4.0, or 2.0x2? I doubt the first is possible, the 2nd might be, using something like [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) or [Audio Router](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router)

Comment: @Tetsujiin I suspect it's not possible on Windows, but I would not be surprised if it could be done on Linux (though it would probably take some serious effort).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When I speak of 4.0 I means that all 4 channel should work independently like, for example, for front - rear effect during film vision. I tried to click all related buttons in windows panels, and I can't imagine why knowing the exact panel I tried could help since it's not working...

Comment: You won't be able to do it directly in Windows because neither output presents itself as a multichannel interface. You have 2 stereo outputs, so all you can do is push the same stereo pair to both of them. You can buy a USB>multichannel converter on eBay for 10 bucks, which will present to your OS as true 5.1 or 7.1, reducible in the control panel to 4.0. Presenting that to Bluetooth might be an issue though unless you can find one with BT built-in.

Comment: Hmmm... I just realised your 'other pair' is internal, so that's not going to work either. I'd give up now, or buy a cheap 5.1 system. You can get those for 20 bucks, entry-level.